# Does a Diagnostics & Usage entry imply an app was installed?

Tags: ios, settings

If an app has an entry in Diagnostics & Usage on a particular day, does that imply that it was installed on that day?

Comment: I assume it was, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The entries you're seeing in Diagnostics and Usage are crash logs for applications on your device.

If a crash log exists for an app, then yes it means it was installed on your device at the time of the crash.